# Got "this" as undefined in ts class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I`m making a rest api with express.js + typescript + typeorm

I was thinking that I've got some problem with AppDataSource or something of this sort, but it's good.

Here is my controller class:

```
import { RequestWithBody } from '@utils/types/request.type'
import { Response } from 'express'
import { AppDataSource } from '../../data-source'
import { Type } from './type.entity'

class TypeController {
    private typeRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Type)

    async create(req: RequestWithBody<{ name: string }>, res: Response) {
        console.log('this', this)

        const { name } = req.body
        const type = this.typeRepository.create({
            name
        })

        const createdType = await this.typeRepository.save(type)
        return res.json(createdType)
    }
}

export default new TypeController()
```

Here is route:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import typeController from './type.controller'

const router = Router()

router.post('/', typeController.create)

export default router
```

Unfortunatelly in the console.log in the create method I got this as undefined:
`this undefined`

If I write the code this way, it will work:

```
async create(req: RequestWithBody<{ name: string }>, res: Response) {

        const { name } = req.body
        const type = AppDataSource.getRepository(Type).create({
            name
        })

        const createdType = await AppDataSource.getRepository(Type).save(type)
        return res.json(createdType)
    }
```

So I have no idea why "this" become undefined

Comment: does `router.post('/', (...args) => typeController.create(...args))` work?
` or `router.post('/', typeController.create.bind(typeController))`

Comment: the value of this within a method depends on how the method is invoked. When router.post('/', typeController.create), the create method being called without bound to the typeController instance, which is cause this to undefined

Comment: what if you use a constructor? ```constructor() { this.typeRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Type); }```

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah this actually work typeController.create.bind(typeController)

Comment: yeah, `this` can be a harsh mistress depending on how the function is called

Comment: @GrafiCode I've tried this one as well. LickingFilth has solved this problem. That's because of typeController.create was passed as callback function in the router

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `typeController.create` as a callback to `router.post`, `this` context inside the `create` method becomes `undefined`.

Simple solution: an arrow function, which binds `this` to the surrounding context :-)

```
create = async (req: RequestWithBody<{ name: string }>, res: Response) => {
        console.log('this', this)

        const { name } = req.body
        const type = this.typeRepository.create({
            name
        })
```

Comment: Thank you, brother. That's still kinda weird for me, after writing in C# for a while :)